# How can I read randomly a line in a file using JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, random-access

Suppose that I have a file with a set of number (more than 20K) in a list like this:

> 85049293
>   86470391
>   87644095
>   85897840
>   87774526

So I would like to crate a JMeter script that will pick 2 of these numbers randomly and use it as input in a http request. I would like that each thread pick 2 different numbers. How can I accomplish this? Which components should I use?

Answer (score 1):

Split you file into 2.
Use 2 CSV datasets where each one will extract one variable, with many simultaneous threads you will have this kind of randomness.

It is not the cleanest solution but I think the most performing.

Another option is to use JSR223 + groovy and code this random access.